# Macbook Pro 2017 Heating Issue while running Windows 10 on Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, high-sierra, temperature

Im new to the Mac Environment.I have got the Macbook for some development purpose.I have completed my work on Xcode and moving on to windows.The main Platform for which i work is Windows,so i have installed windows on my Macbook pro using Bootcamp.

The bottom panel of the Macbook runs visibly hot when running Windows compared to running High Sierra.I have Visual Studio 2017 open and even in idle conditions the Macbook appears hot.

See the system temperature
[image]

I have reduced the CPU Performance and change the cooling to active in power options.
[image]

I have downloaded new software from apple using the Apple Update tool.

I have noticed that the AMD Gpu is being used to power windows on Bootcamp.

I was wondering if this kind of stuff is normal.Im worried if this is overheating and it might compromise the life of the Macbook for which i have spend a lot of money on.

Please advice

Comment: It might depend on what you call 'hot'. I don't see anything in those figures to worry about. 100°C is 'hot'.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is this a good tool to monitor the temperature? By hot i mean it gets uncomfortable to place the Macbook on my lap due to heat.

Comment: So long as the software is reporting the temperatures accurately, they are well within bounds. You might find something that would let you ramp the fans harder than Windows wants to do it, but idk of anything specific.

Comment: @Tetsujin Have you experienced issues like mine before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The needn't worry over the core temperatures you've shown in your screenshots (47-50 degC). And your system will always run hotter when you are using Windows in Bootcamp... I don't know all of the reasons for this, but it's just "the way it's always been" on my Macs.

As for your questions, "I was wondering if this kind of stuff is normal. I'm worried if this is overheating and it might compromise the life of the Macbook for which i have spend a lot of money on.":

It's a [well-known fact that heat adversely affects the life of electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation). But again, for the temperatures you've recorded, I wouldn't worry. You may find that when Windows 10 performs some compute-intensive tasks that the temperature goes a bit higher. [Apple has some guidelines on temperature management](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201640). And [here's a Q&A that provides additional information](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-3526478/maximum-operating-temperature.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Are you using MacBook Pro 2017?

Comment: You are welcome. Mine is a "late 2016", but fairly similar I think. I also have a late 2011 w/ the 17" screen :)  Couldn't wait for a re-intro of the 17" display, so I caved last year, and bought this one.

Answer (score 1):

After almost 8 years of wondering why Mac computers (e.g. 2013 and 2020 Macbook Pro for my part) were overheating so much (reaching 100°C on both models when fully stressed) with Windows (installed with or without bootcamp), I finally discovered why thanks to your hint @Techno:

My guess is that Mac motherboards do not handle the turbo boost mode of modern CPUs. It is probably handled directly within MacOS, therefore Windows is lost and keeps using 100% of the maximum possible CPU frequencies. But the CPU turbo boost mode should be used only for very short periods of time, not all the time like it does here.

**THE FIX**

On Windows OS, go to the Advanced Power Options, and then under "Processor Power Managment":

- first set "System Cooling Policy" on ACTIVE for both Battery and Plugged in (by default set on PASSIVE on Battery, but it seems wrong except if you lower the "Maximum Processor State" a lot (maybe like 50%).
- then set the "Maximum Processor State" at 99% for both Plugged in and Battery (lower on Battery if you want to save it). That's it!

If you open HWMonitor while doing this, you will notice that your CPU frequencies drop directly to the normal frequencies of your CPU (e.g almost always at 3000 MHz before = turbo boost frequencies, and at 1995 MHz after the fix). If you go lower than 99% you will notice that the frequencies change with normal ratios.

The downside of this is that we loose the turbo boost option of our CPUs, but in my opinion it is better than having the fans always running at their maximum, and damaging your hardware (CPU, but also the motherboard itself when it reachs 100°C!)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for sharing .. will give it a try and get back...